# Authentication with file_get_contents

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, file-get-contents

I am using PHP file_get_contents to authenticate users, my scripts work with every Facebook user except my Facebook account that the app is registered with. The URL file_get_contents uses works when copied into the browser address bar and returns access token but does not work with file_get_contents. It returns bad request.

Is it not possible to authenticate with the Facebook account that the app is registered with?

Comment: Of course you can auth with your own app developer/admin account. But why are you bothering yourself with the trouble of making your own requests using file_get_contents (which makes error handling and debugging quite a pain, as you can clearly see), instead of just using the PHP SDK?

Comment: Sorry, don't like PHP SDK. This problem only works with my account that the app is registered with and no other account. Thats why I ask the original question.

Comment: Well, if you don’t “like” the SDK (for no apparent reason), then _“good luck to you, sir” :-P_ Debugging and error handling when making requests against the API “manually” using file_get_contents can be a real PITA sometimes – whereas with the SDK you get straight exceptions when something went wrong, and so seeing the reason for the error is much easier. So take I from me, _not_ using the SDK for common stuff that it’s very well capable of doing and instead doing all that stuff yourself, is just plain _stupid_ (sorry, but it’s the truth).

Comment: [cont.] So if you want to find out why your request using file_get_contents went wrong, you have to add a `context` parameter with `ignore_errors` set, so that you get to see the actual error message Facebook sends along with the 400 Bad Request response header …

Comment: I have to use file_get_contents to make calls to the graph api and FQL so it seemed logical to also use f_g_c for authentication. Like I say it works perfectly for every user apart from the one the app is registered with. Thanks for your last tip context parameter.